# Caret and the trainControl function

Tags: r, modeling, r-squared, caret

I am fairly new to using the caret package and ran into a question about the trainControl function.  I have a model linear regression model where I used

```
train(x,y,method="glmStepAIC")
```

If I leave the script like this I get an R2 of roughly 22%.  When I add

```
trainControl(method="cv")
```

So we now have...

```
train(x,y,method="glmStepAIC",trainControl(method="cv"))
```

the R2 jumps to about 32% but the parameter estimates don't change at all
The method glmStepAIC has no tuning parameters associated with it so why and how am I getting such a difference in the R2 (as well as RMSE)